# UpdateOneModel, with Upsert - error _id Mongodb C# MongoDB.Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to perform a bulkwrite with c# https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/crud/writing/#bulk-writes - I could have a list of documents from 70-80K.

```
var correlationIdFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.AnyIn("CorrelationId", ninKeysRecon);
var missingData = collection.Find(correlationIdFilter).ToList();
```

Missing Data Data Sample

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("61dd323bfe35f25bb2dcde8e"), 
    "CorrelationId" : "17bd621d-e47f-4ab1-9004-9543294a4549", 
    "Key" : "123", 
    "Date" : "2016-06-28T00:00:00", 
    "CurrentDate" : ISODate("2022-01-11T07:31:07.011+0000"), 
    "SourceSystem" : "abc", 
    "SourceEntity" : "source"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("61dd323bfe35f25bb2dcd123"), 
    "CorrelationId" : "18bd621d-e47f-4ab1-9004-9543294a4549", 
    "Key" : "123232324", 
    "Date" : "2016-06-28T00:00:00", 
    "CurrentDate" : ISODate("2022-01-11T07:31:07.011+0000"), 
    "SourceSystem" : "abc", 
    "SourceEntity" : "source"
},
.
.
.
{100K Documents}
```

Then I createoptions and bulkOps

```
var options = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true };
var bulkOps = new List<WriteModel<BsonDocument>>();
```

I dont know if I need to loop through missingData to create a new UpdateOneModel() but I am struggling to see where or how to create a filter because when I set _id as a filter, I get the error  _id field is immutable.  I do not want to overwrite the _id but I simply want to achieve something like this

```
collection.UpdateMany(correlationIdFilter, missingBson, options);
```

Or if I have to create a for loop, I have tried:

```
foreach(var data in missingBson)
{
    var upsert = new UpdateOneModel<BsonDocument>(
    new BsonDocument("_id", 1),
    new BsonDocument("$set", data)) { IsUpsert = true };
    bulkOps.Add(upsert);
}

collection.BulkWrite(bulkOps);
```

I get the error:

WriteErrors: [ { Category : "Uncategorized", Code : 66, Message : "Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'" } ].'

removing - { IsUpsert = true } runs fine but doesn't do any upserting which I need.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument passed to [`UpdateOneModel`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_UpdateOneModel_1.htm) is the filter. The filter tells MongoDB which document you want to update. You pass `new BsonDocument("_id", 1)`, which tells MongoDB you want to update the document with an `_id` of `1`. `_id` is a [special field in MongoDB documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#field-names):

> The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type other than an array. If the _id contains subfields, the subfield names cannot begin with a ($) symbol

`_id` is immutable, meaning it cannot be changed. This is an issue because the data you are passing to [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) contains an `_id` field that is not `1`.

Instead, in the filter document you should be passing the `_id` of the document you are trying to insert.

```
foreach(var data in missingBson)
{
    var upsert = new UpdateOneModel<BsonDocument>(
    new BsonDocument("_id", data._id),
    new BsonDocument("$set", data)) { IsUpsert = true };
    bulkOps.Add(upsert);
}
```

This way the `_id` fields match, and you are not attempting to update a document with an `_id` of `1` for each write operation.

Answer (score 0):

try this, with bulkWriteAsycn func. You can use this func. with a timer

```
var requests = new List<WriteModel<T>>();
    
    foreach(var data in dataList)
    {
      requests.Add(
        new UpdateOneModel<T>
        (
         filter,
         Builders<T>.Update(x=>x.key, data.key) // custom updates
        )
        {IsUpsert=true};
      )
    }
    
    await collection.BulkWriteAsync(requests);
```

this *filter* is your custom filter for updated fields.
**Needs attention for new record (all fields are possibly)**

Filter Ex:

> Builders.Filter.Where(item=> item.id == data.id)

see *[UpdateOneModel.IsUpsert Property](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.1/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_UpdateOneModel_1_IsUpsert.htm)*